# Php regular expression for date

Tags: php, regex

something is wrong in my php regular expression which is not accepting `0` before Month and date. My date formate is `MM/DD/YY`. It could be 6/6/2014 or 06/06/2014.

```
if(!empty($datepicker)){
    if(preg_match("/^([0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4}$/", $datepicker) !==1)
        $err[] = "Invalid date of birth";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it as:

```
/^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4}$/
// ^^                ^^
```

Comment: @creativeartbd I like to use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3pqdxlKkjg3KOoX-) to understand regular expressions